# List all system certificate stores

Tags: c#, certificate, pki

I'm looking for a way to get all system certificate stores, in any [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storelocation.aspx)  (`CurrentUser` or `LocalMachine`).

The `StoreLocation` enumeration clearly won't include user-defined certificate stores created with `X509Store(String)` or `X509Store(String, StoreLocation)`. Also this doesn't define [other standard stores](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961648.aspx) such as `SPC` or `Request`.

I've looked at the `crypto32.dll` API and I couldn't see anything relevant in there apart from register/unregister.

Non file-system based stores appear in the registry (eg `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root`). The [PowerShell Certificate Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347615.aspx) can interrogate stores. Is this -- querying the registry -- what it's doing under the hood? Would such a hand-rolled solution be portable between XP/Vista/7/8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, our SecureBlackbox product does what you need via CryptoAPI, namely [CertEnumSystemStore()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/aa376058.aspx) function. It has plenty of parameters, though.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! (I guess I missed that in the other 475 cryptoAPI methods/properties). Now I just need to get to grips with hitting the unmanaged world from C#...

Comment: @Martin check http://pinvoke.net/ . While it doesn't contain CertEnumSystemStore (I've checked), it contains similar functions which will help you get started.